# How to use Azure Media Service Live Stream with Apple AirPlay

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am using Azure Media Service to live stream an event. My source is a HD SDI feed being captured via an AJA Kona LHi card and sent to Azure using Wirecast.

I'm using the default settings in Wirecast for Azure Media Service. I am using standard encoding and the 720p preset. I am using the Azure Media Player embedded in a private site.

Everything seems to work however iOS devices are unable to AirPlay the stream. The video plays correctly on the device but no AirPlay controls are available.

If I use the exact same setup to stream my webcam the AirPlay controls are available. Is there some specific configuration required to make this work reliably?

Comment: Hi, Jacob. I read your post carefully, but I think azure-media-services does not matter with the problems. If azure-media-service don't support airplay when you use webcam, it may be azure's problem. So I guess, may be the problem are wirecast or  AJA Kona LHi card . They are not compatible with software and hardware.

Comment: And I suggest , may  be you can use other software to push you streams like OBS to replace Wirecast, good luck !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iPad, Azure Media Player by default streams the videos in DASH. You need to specify the techorder to use give HLS a higher priority, e.g.:

```
var myOptions = {
                    techOrder: ["html5", "azureHtml5JS", "flashSS"],                    
                    autoplay: false,
                    controls: true,
                    width: "640",
                    height: "400",
                };
var myPlayer = amp("azuremediaplayer", myOptions);
```

If you don't see the AirPlay button on the video player, you can do a swipe down gesture on the upper right region of the screen and bring up the "Quick controls" to access AirPlay:

[image]

If this still doesn't work, reply with the url of your webpage and I can take a look.

Comment: I've noticed that changing the tech order breaks the player on Smart TVs.